# How return a result of my method executed in thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've a method who return a result (return an integer), my method is executed in a Thread for load 40 000 objects, i return an integer who count the number objects loaded. My question is, How return the int with the Thread ? Actually, the result is returned directly and is equal to 0.

```
public int ajouter(params) throws DaoException, ConnectException {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mActivity, "Title",
            "Message", true);
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Str_Requete = "SELECT * FROM Mytable";
                ResultSet result = ExecuteQuery(Str_Base, Str_Requete);
                Index = addObjects(result);
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return Index;
}
```

When i call my method in my mainActivity :

```
 int test = myObjs.ajouter(params);
```

test is equal to 0, the value is returned directly...
My constraint is didnt use AsyncTask.

Comment: make a static counter and update it inside your thread `run` method and return it.

Comment: For Heaven's sake, please follow Android naming conventions.

Comment: Rustam, I think using a static variable to accomodate the result of a calculation done on another thread is a horrible suggestion. It will not be thread safe, you will not be able to run several different jobs in parallel, and there's no way for the calling code to know *when* the calculation is complete. This is NOT what static variables should be used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of using a Thread is not to block the calling code while performing the task of the thread. Thread.start() returns immediately, but in the meantime a new thread is started in parallel to the current thread which will execute the code in the run() method.

So by definition there is no such thing as *returning* a value from a thread execution. You have to somehow send a signal back from the thread that performed the task to the thread in which you need the result. There are many ways of doing this, there's the standard Java wait/notify methods, there is the Java concurrency library etc.

Since this is Android, and I assume your calling code is running on the main thread, it's probably wise to use the functionality of Handler. And in fact, you are already doing that - you have a Handler that closes the dialog when the thread is done with its work - but for some reason you seem to expect the result of that work to be ready before it has even started. It would be reasonable to extend your existing Handler with some code that does something with the calculated value and remove the code that returns the value of a variable before or at the same time as it's being calculated by another thread.

I also strongly encourage you to study some concurrency tutorial such as [Oracle's concurrency lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) or [Android Thread guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) to really understand what's going on in the background. Writing concurrent code without mastering the concepts is bound to fail sooner or later, because it's in the nature of concurrency that multiple things are happening at the same time, will finish in random order etc. It may not fail often, but you will go crazy wondering why something that works 90% of the time suddenly fails. That's why topics such as atomicity, thread synchronization etc are critical to comprehend.

Edit: Simple Android example of starting a worker thread, performing some work, posting back event to main thread.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    ...

    private void doSomeWorkInBackground() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                // do slow work, this may be blocking
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // this code will run on main thread, 
                        // updating your UI or whatever you need. 
                        // Hence, code here must NOT be blocking.
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();

        // This code will be executed immediately on the main thread, and main thread will not be blocked
    }
```

You could in this example also use `Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)`.
Please consider however that `AsyncTask` basically wraps this kind of functionality in a very convenient way, so if it suits your purposes you should consider using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: If I understand, i have to return my value in my handler ?

Comment: I've found a part of solution, I use the framework Executor with Callable and Future but i've a problem, when i call .get on my Future task the UI thread is blocked, know a solution ?

Comment: Future.get() is supposed to block unless the work is completed already, please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get().

In Android, the main thread uses an event loop and should NEVER hang, i.e., NEVER call any blocking methods. Instead your thread should post an event to the main thread, using Handler.post(Runnable) or similar techniques. In your particular case I am not so sure Future and Callable really adds any added value. I will update my answer with an easy example of start worker -> perform work -> post back.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use AsyncTask or ForkJoin, then you could implement an Interface e.g. callback in your main class.

In your Example you dont wait until the Thread is done... thread.join

One Solution:
Your Thread is a extra class with an constructor to hold the reference to the calling class.

```
public Interface callback
{
public int done();
}


public class main implements callback
{
...

CustomThread t = new CustomThread(this)

...
}


public class CustomThread extends Thread
{

    private Callback cb;

    public CustomThread(Callback cb)
    {
        this.cb=cb;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    //when done
    cb.done(int)
 }
```

Comment: Not sure this is such a good solution. Note that this only enables calling a callback method in the thread where the work was done. Generally you want to signal the result back to the thread which requested work to be offloaded to a worker thread. Especially in Android it's very likely that the OP wants to do something with the result such as update some kind of UI, and even though you could of course invoke a handler or runOnUiThread call from the callback implementation, I don't really see any added value with your scheme over an anonymous thread class or an AsyncTask.

Comment: i agree with you that my scheme has no more value than an AsyncTask.

Normaly i would use Java concurreny / forkjoin. Maybe i misunderstood the question: How can i return the value of a thread.execute without using asynctask. I wanted to show an possible alternative.